# How to get size of image inside SVG in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

How can I get the real height and width of an image inside a SVG element in HTML, when the `width` attribute of it is expressed in percentage?

HTML code:

```
<svg id="svg-container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <image id="content-image" href="page-003.jpg" width="90%">
    
  </image>
</svg>
```

JS code:

```
let el;
el = document.getElementById("content-image");
console.log(el.clientWidth);
el = document.getElementById("svg-container");
console.log(el.clientWidth);
```

The two `console.log` commands output 0 and 300, respectively. How can I get the real width of the image object?

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s1t6ajLv/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth),

> The Element.clientWidth property is zero for inline elements and elements with no CSS;

You have to use `width` property from [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

```
const contentImage = document.getElementById("content-image");
console.log(contentImage.getBoundingClientRect().width);

const svgContainer = document.getElementById("svg-container");
console.log(svgContainer.getBoundingClientRect().width);
```

**Snippet**

```js
const contentImage = document.getElementById("content-image");
console.log(contentImage.getBoundingClientRect().width);

const svgContainer = document.getElementById("svg-container");
console.log(svgContainer.getBoundingClientRect().width);
```

```html
<svg id="svg-container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <image id="content-image" href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575936123452-b67c3203c357?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aW1hZ2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D&w=1000&q=80" width="90%"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: Indeed in my particular case it's better to use `getComputedStyle`, since with `getBoundingClientRect` returns the width including padding, margin and border.

Comment: ``let { width,height } = svgContainer.getBoundingClientRect()`` makes it easier

Answer (score 0):

`naturalHeight` & `naturalWidth` property returns the original `height` & `width` of an image.

**NB:** This property is read-only

The natural height and width of an image are not directly accessible through the SVG image element. Fortunately, by loading the image into a temporary `img` element and eventually accessing its native dimensions, you may still get the image's original dimensions.

**HTML code:**

```
<svg id="svg-container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <image id="content-image" href="page-003.jpg" width="90%">
    
  </image>
</svg>
```

**JS code:**

```
const svgContainer = document.getElementById('svg-container');
const contentImage = document.getElementById('content-image');

const img = new Image();
img.src = contentImage.getAttribute('href');

contentImage.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const height = img.naturalHeight;
  const width = img.naturalWidth;

  console.log(`Height: ${height}, Width: ${width}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### SVG `baseVal` property

Depending on your task, you might also get the current width from the parsed **SVG node object** via [`baseVal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedString/baseVal) property.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  let width = contentImage.width.baseVal.value;
  let width2 = contentImage2.width.baseVal.value;
  let width3 = contentImage3.width.baseVal.value;
  let width4 = contentImage4.width.baseVal.value;

  console.log('widths:', width, width2, width3, width4)

});
```

```css
svg{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h3>1. No viewBox – get element's HTML DOM width</h3>
<svg width="300px" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <image id="contentImage" href="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" width="90%"  />
</svg>

<h3>2. Width relative to viewBox – SVG DOM width</h3>
<svg width="300px" id="svg2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 150">
  <image id="contentImage2" href="https://picsum.photos/id/237/500/300" width="90%" />
</svg>

<h3>3. Width relative to viewBox – SVG DOM width</h3>
<svg width="600px" id="svg3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 150">
  <image id="contentImage3" href="https://picsum.photos/id/237/500/300" width="90%" />
</svg>

<h3>4. Same layout width but relative to SVG viewBox</h3>
<svg width="300px" id="svg4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 150 75">
  <image id="contentImage4" href="https://picsum.photos/id/237/500/300" width="90%" />
</svg>
```

1. Example 3 – with a specified `viewBox` – returns width=270 although it's rendered twice as wide as the original svg.
2. Example 4 on the other hand, returns a width of 135 (SVG user units), – albeit rendered at the same size (300x150px).

### "Real width" of SVG elements vs. SVG DOM width

As explained by [BadPiggie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76489118/how-to-get-size-of-image-inside-svg-in-javascript-typescript/76489619#76489619) `getBoundingClientRect()` returns the current bounding box as rendered.

However, if you need to manipulate SVG elements' widths – `baseVal` property can be handy for converting percentage based values to **absolute user SVG units** (... admittedly, absolute is ... relative)